# MongoDB not working with delete method when using deleteOne

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using node and mongoose to build my first API Restful but I'm having some problems with the "Delete" method.

```
async function remove(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.params
  
    const remove = await ProductsModel.deleteOne({ _id: id })
    
    const message = remove.ok ? 'success' : 'error'
  
    res.send({
      message,
    })
  }


module.exports = {
    remove
}
```

The route is correct

```
router.delete('/products/:id', ProductController.remove)
```

Postman response is always errors, I've tried different ID's, but wont work.

I've tried different ID's, and searching for the `deleteOne` method guide, but couldn't find the error

Comment: One of the common causes of error is that you are supplying plain string of `_id` while the `_id` field is `ObjectId` type. Make sure you are comparing same data type.

Comment: What is the error? It will be simple to solve once you post the error.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at my code and discover that it was deleting, but the "if" was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID of the document you are trying to delete exists but still isn't found or deleted, something else to try is casting the ID string to an ObjectId:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');    
const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
const remove = await ProductsModel.deleteOne({ _id: objectId })
```